# Add to Cart" button to "Buy on Amazon" and auto-redirect to affiliate link using WooZone plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Question:

I am working on an e-commerce website using the WooZone plugin for product imports. My goal is to replace the standard **"Add to Cart"** button with a **"Buy on Amazon"** button for products available on Amazon through my affiliate program. I am using **Electro Theme** for WordPress.

I have already imported the products using WooZone, but I'm not sure how to proceed with modifying the button and implementing the auto-redirect functionality. My intention is that when a user clicks on the "Buy on Amazon" button, they should be redirected to the respective product page on Amazon using my affiliate link.

Could anyone guide me on achieving this functionality with the WooZone plugin or any other recommended approach?

Any code examples or step-by-step instructions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Woocommerce supports few types of products - Simple Product, Grouped Product,Virtual Product,Downloadable Product,External/Affiliate Product,Variable Product . In your case just change your product to External provide the link. The button text is also set from there but in case all your products are from amazon and want same text then check 3rd example from here - https://metorik.com/blog/change-the-add-to-cart-text-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been successfully resolved by adhering to the following steps:

1. Navigate to the product section and click "All products."
2. Choose the specific product that requires editing and proceed by
   selecting the "Edit" button.
3. Within the "Product data" drop-down menu, opt for "External / Affiliate products."
4. Input the desired text into the designated Button text box, and ensure to save the changes.

The process is now complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just Swift to external product. Any other solution is perhaps on the custumization.